# Git: the meaning of object 'size' returned by git verify-pack

Tags: git, git-verify-pack

The [git verify-pack](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-verify-pack) command has a `-v` option which outputs a lot of diagnostic information for each object found in the packfile. However, the value returned by the `size` field for a deltified object is not matching my hazy expectations - I thought that it would be something like the uncompressed 'true' size of the Git object? What's the actual meaning of this field?

Specifically, I have a Git packfile which contains a large object:

```
$ git cat-file -s 7daa9e75f86aa168748aef6c16c76b2acee1acca
61464170
```

*(ie the object size is about 58MB, which is indeed what I see when I check the file out)*

However, the line returned for this object by `git verify-pack -v` is this:

```
7daa9e75f86aa168748aef6c16c76b2acee1acca blob   568352 529608 770759074 1 27e47895a3822906eb31b05fe674ad470296c12e
```

*(a full copy of the verify-pack output is available [here](https://gist.github.com/rtyley/6138921/raw/7de67ceeb6acef43a92acf26ed43d88d146beb80/verify-pack.txt))*

As you can see (after reading [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-verify-pack#_output_format) for `git verify-pack`), this object is stored *deltafied*, and the definition of the columns is this:

```
SHA1 type size size-in-packfile offset-in-packfile depth base-SHA1
```

So 'size' for this object is **568352** (and 'size-in-packfile' is 529608) - but what does that mean, given that the actual object size is **61464170** bytes? The magnitude-order difference in size must mean that the size figure refers just to the delta?

Comment: Can you post the complete output of `git verify-pack -v`?

Comment: Thanks @devnull - the full verify-pack output is available here: https://gist.github.com/rtyley/6138921/raw/7de67ceeb6acef43a92acf26ed43d88d146beb80/verify-pack.txt

Comment: Has the size of the file has changed a bit between the post and the verify-pack output?

Comment: You already have the answer now but `27e47895a3822906eb31b05fe674ad470296c12e blob   61797057 61593409 709165665` from the output would also give you a clue.  Also see [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Packfiles) -- last couple of paras specifically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, see [this diagram](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/technical/pack-format.txt).  Then, based on the source (`builtin/index-pack.c`), the value in the fourth field is:

```
(unsigned long)(obj[1].idx.offset - obj->idx.offset)
```

which is the raw packed-up size (`obj[1]` is the next object after this one, or the trailer).  As the stored item is deltified, that's the size of the delta-compressed data plus overhead.  The value in the third field is `obj->size` (the first size value from the overhead area).

(To get the actual data, or even its size, you have to inflate the stream a bit and then look at the delta headers.  The object's "true" size is encoded in the header as the *second* size value.  See `get_size_from_delta` in `sha1_file.c`, `get_delta_hdr_size` in `delta.h`, and the "offset encoding" in the diagram.)

---

Edit to add: OK, re-reading the question, you're asking more about why the fourth size is so much smaller than the third one.  That would be because the third one is the inflated (but not de-delta-ed) size of the object.  So: size-in-packfile (field 4) is after deflating, but also includes a bit of header overhead; size of delta-compressed file (field 3) is, well, obvious; and size of ultimate file, after undoing delta compression, is in the header whose byte count is included with the size-in-packfile (field 4).

Extra edit: the offset-in-packfile (field 5) is `obj->idx.offset`.  That's where you have to `lseek()` in the pack file to start reading the object (I think, I've got some confusing code in front of me for handling `OBJ_OFS_DELTA` too :-) ).

Comment: Thanks for looking into this @torek. I appreciate your answer but I think I'm either misunderstanding you or you might have made an off-by-one error in your explanation. Could you amend your answer to include these three values from the verify-pack output (size: 568352, size-in-packfile: 529608, offset-in-packfile: 770759074) and place the C expressions given above in your answer appropriately against each one?

Comment: I've just edited my question in response to your answer revision (http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18016693/3) - really, I wanted to know why 'size' in verify-pack is 568352, when the actual full object size is 61464170 bytes.

Comment: I read a description of the delta format somewhere, at some point, but don't remember the details.  But the `obj->size` field is how big the deflated item (call it "the delta") will be, and to recover the original object, git has to de-delta that, by going to the "underlying" object and extracting that and applying the changes given in the delta.  Or, you could say: the delta is super-effective, it stored the modified object using just 568352 bytes of instructions for "how to change the other one into me".

Comment: Fair enough... so the shortest answer is that 'size' in verify-pack is just the size of the delta-representation, not the eventual size of the reconstructed blob. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With Git 2.21 (Q1 2019), the meaning of "`objectsize`" is clarified, as the "`--format=<placeholder>`" option of `for-each-ref`, `branch` and `tag` learned to show a few more traits of objects that can be learned by the object_info API.

See [commit 59012fe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/59012fe5e8f7485a48544324054f24aebfff3b38), [commit 5610d9f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5610d9ff0d04de8a2d685957e6dd9db911930b00), [commit 33311fa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33311fa1ade8ca955f0e56e521f7d759d30a3da0), [commit f4ee22b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f4ee22b52620827ccd0ec38e6cbc301b8aabded8), [commit 5305a55](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5305a55348c102475c1bcb56e8fcbabe37178112), [commit 1867ce6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1867ce6cbec9c8f23f958cb675de129fcd6471a4) (24 Dec 2018) by [Olga Telezhnaya (`telezhnaya`)](https://github.com/telezhnaya).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 55574bd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55574bd04ada4dab255dad687665ee7578bc6a32), 18 Jan 2019)</sup>

> ### `ref-filter`: add `objectsize:disk` option

> Add new formatting option `objectsize:disk` to know exact size that object takes up on disk.

The [`git for-each-ref` man page now states](https://github.com/git/git/blob/55574bd04ada4dab255dad687665ee7578bc6a32/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt#L129-L142):

> ```
> objectsize:
> ```
>
> The size of the object (the **same as '`git cat-file -s`' reports**).
> Append `:disk` to get the size, in bytes, that the object takes up on disk.
>
> ```
> deltabase:
> ```
>
> This expands to the object name of the delta base for the given object, if it is stored as a delta.
> Otherwise, it expands to the null object name (all zeroes).
>
> ### Caveats:
>
> Note that the sizes of objects on disk are reported accurately, but care should be taken in drawing conclusions about which refs or objects are responsible for disk usage.
> **The size of a packed non-delta object may be much larger than the size of objects which delta against it, but the choice of which object is the base and which is the delta is arbitrary and is subject to change during a repack**.
>
> Note also that multiple copies of an object may be present in the object database; in this case, it is undefined which copy's size or delta base will be reported.

So you can compare those values with the one reported by `git verify-pack -v`, as a `git for-each-ref` is now (5+ years later: 2013-2018) able to display more data.

---

Git 2.44 (Q1 2024) illustrates that the `objectsize` should not be hard-coded.

See [commit fbc6526](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fbc6526ea651565889e437ce7b12c762ef858813) (12 Dec 2023) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6db745e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6db745e1f5ae2ea71f8c7d6b99bf37c8e1a7acfb), 27 Dec 2023)</sup>

> ### [`t6300`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fbc6526ea651565889e437ce7b12c762ef858813): avoid hard-coding object sizes
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Ondrej Pohorelsky</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> [f4ee22b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f4ee22b52620827ccd0ec38e6cbc301b8aabded8) ("`ref-filter`: add tests for objectsize:disk", 2018-12-24, Git v2.21.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55574bd04ada4dab255dad687665ee7578bc6a32) listed in [batch #3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/16a465bc018d09e9d7bbbdc5f40a7fb99c21f8ef)) hard-coded the expected object sizes.
> Coincidentally the size of commit and tag is the same with zlib at the default compression level.
>
> [1f5f8f3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f5f8f3e85d9afeb4c2688de9a192351f616f143) ("`t6300`: abstract away SHA-1-specific constants", 2020-02-22, Git v2.27.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f8cb64e3d4d512a86c1b7b3aa584f11740b3d038) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3bab5d56259722843359702bc27111475437ad2a)) encoded the sizes as a single value, which coincidentally also works with sha256.
>
> Different compression libraries like zlib-ng may arrive at different values.
> Get them from the file system instead of hard-coding them to make switching the compression library (or changing the compression level) easier.

Answer (score 0):

There was a recent patch series [[RFC/PATCH 0/4] cat-file --batch-disk-sizes](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/229761)  discussion which included ["[PATCH 07/10] cat-file: add %(objectsize:disk) format atom"](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/230048)  which may be of interest if you are into compiling from source.